# How access embedded control in style from style trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-style

I want to create style that can change embedded in him controls, like here I want to change "Source" of "ImageIco" but I get errors. Is it possible to make it inside style? Because all examples what I see use additional code or writing additional code in window itself.

Problematic part:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="IcoImage" Property="Source" Value="{DynamicResource InfoIco.Red}"/>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
        <Setter TargetName="IcoImage" Property="Source" Value="{DynamicResource InfoIco.White}"/>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

All style code:

```
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}"
       TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
       x:Key="RedsInfoButton">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                          Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                          Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">

                        <Image Name="IcoImage" 
                               Source="{DynamicResource InfoIco.White}"/>

                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    </Style.Setters>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="IcoImage" Property="Source" Value="{DynamicResource InfoIco.Red}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="IcoImage" Property="Source" Value="{DynamicResource InfoIco.White}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>

</Style>

<BitmapImage x:Key="InfoIco.White" UriSource="/WPFDesign/Data/Images/InfoWhite.ico"/>
<BitmapImage x:Key="InfoIco.Red" UriSource="/WPFDesign/Data/Images/InfoRed.ico"/>
```

Comment: *{DynamicResource InfoIco.White}

Comment: You may move the Triggers into the ControlTemplate, to `<ControlTemplate.Triggers>`.Note that you do not need two Triggers for a boolean property. One default value and one Trigger should be sufficient.